# Azure Web Sites Config Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, webforms

I'm trying to deploy a mostly empty asp.net webforms app (with a custom httpmodule specified in web.config) to Azure and getting the following error:

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file:
>   Access to the path
>   'D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\xqhbvcov.tmp' is
>   denied.
>
> Source Error:
>
> [No relevant source lines]
>
> Source File:
>   D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
>   Line: 0
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.276

Any ideas?  I'm not sure what other information may be pertinent so if I'm missing something vital please ask and I'll supply it.

Entire web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <!--<httpModules>
      <add name="AbcdModule" type="org.abcd.abcdHttpModule"/>
    </httpModules>-->
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="AbcdModule" type="org.abcd.abcdHttpModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you post your web.config (or parts of it, especially the part with the custom HttpModule).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had discussion with Windows Azure Websites team and found that custom HTTP Modules are supported with Windows Azure Websites so they should work and problem could occur depend on how complex the registration is.

For the sake of testing, I use the link below to create a custom HTTP Module and tested it in Azure Website which worked without any issue:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

If you can provide more info about your custom HTTP Module (which seems to be part of org.abcd  namspace and anything else) we sure can help. Alternatively you can submit the request at [Azure Websites Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurewebsitespreview/threads), someone can help you directly.

Comment: Thank you for going the extra mile.  It turns out our code was doing something a bit crazy, setting the executionTimeout value in machine.config.  I was unaware of this previously.  I assume WebSites are a medium trust environment, which would explain why that's not allowed.  So all is well.